# Ошибка websocket workerman php

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, ssl, workerman

Случаются ошибки после запуска вебсокет сервера.
Библиотека Workerman.
В консоли прописываю php server.php start
Какое-то время сервер работает, все хорошо. Но потом сам отключается, т.к. не вижу его в netstat -tulpn
Помимо этого, в консоли всплывает такая ошибка
SSL handshake error: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
Перерыл весь интернет, так и не понял как это все исправлять.

start.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Workerman\Worker;
    $context = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'local_cert'  => '/var/www/httpd-cert/admin/pokepower.ru_le1.crtca',
            'local_pk'    => '/var/www/httpd-cert/admin/pokepower.ru_le1.key',
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
        )
    );
$ws_worker = new Worker("websocket://site.ru:2346",$context);
$ws_worker->transport = 'ssl';
$ws_worker->onWorkerStart = function() use (&$users){
    $inner_tcp_worker = new Worker("tcp://site.ru:1234");
    $inner_tcp_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data) use (&$users) {
       //
    };
    $inner_tcp_worker->listen();
};
$ws_worker->onConnect = function($connection) use (&$users){
    $connection->onWebSocketConnect = function($connection) use (&$users){
        $users[$_GET['user']] = $connection;
    };
};
```

js

```
socket_user = new WebSocket('wss://site.php:2346/?user='+HASH_USER);
```

Т.е. это все поработает-поработает, а потом отключается не знаю из-за чего.

Подскажите что делать, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

если далее по коду вызываемому в onMessages возникает ошибка или выход из программы (exit/die), то Workerman останавливается

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]